# Unable to connect to Centrifugo v2.4.0 from client application nodeJS

Tags: centrifuge

Here is my client code.

```
let Centrifuge = require("centrifuge");
var SockJS = require('sockjs-client');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');


var info = { "sub": "1", "exp": 300,"info": '{ "name": "Venkat" }' }
var secret = "<<token_hmac_secret_key>>"


var centrifuge = new Centrifuge("http://127.0.0.1:8000/connection/sockjs/",  {
sockjs: SockJS
})

var gentoken = jwt.sign(info, secret, { algorithm: 'HS256'});

centrifuge.setToken(gentoken);
centrifuge.connect();
centrifuge.on("connect", function (context) {
console.log("CONNECT:", context);
// now client connected to Centrifugo and authorized
});
centrifuge.on("disconnect", function (context) {
console.log("DISCONNECT:", context);
// do whatever you need in case of disconnect from server
});
```

After executing the above code i am getting response as:

> node src/client.js
>   DISCONNECT: **{ reason: 'invalid token', reconnect: false }**